# grepping multiple lines from a file

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to grep in order multiple lines of a file.
An example of the file `originalfile.txt` could be:

```
num=12
workers not specified
length= 128
Using array element 
num= 24 
workers not specified
length= 128
Using array element 
......
```

I want to `grep` only valuable lines like all those with `num` and `length`:

```
num=12
length= 128
num= 24 
length= 128
......
```

I know how to `grep` for just one pattern, say `num` but I don't know how to do it for more than one pattern.

```
$ grep "num" originalfile.txt
```

It turns out that I have some parameters in the same line that  `awk` does not seem to find,i.e:

`.... time=  1.234 Gflop/s=  3.4556  .....`

It filters the first one, but not Gflop/s. Is there a way to recursvely find on the same line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `-E` option

From [man grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

> -E, --extended-regexp
>
> Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (see below).

```
$ grep -E 'length|num' data
num=12
length= 128
num= 24 
length= 128
```

Update if you want to only get the numbers you can pipe to `awk`

```
grep -E 'length|num' data | awk -F'= ?' '{print $2}'
```

But then you can do it all in a signle awk command, and avoid grep

```
awk -F'= ?' '/length/||/num/{print $2}' data
```

Comment: That was useful. Any idea of how to print just the element after `=`, i.e. just the numbers?

Comment: Your `awk` script doesn't account for the space.

Comment: @sudo_O Now it does... with a bit of plagiarism :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass multiple patterns to grep with the `-e` option

```
grep -e num -e length
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
$ grep '^\w*=' file
num=12
length= 128
num= 24 
length= 128
```

Explanation:

```
^   # Start of line
\w  # Word class, shorthand for [a-zA-Z0-9_]
*   # Quantifier (zero or more)
=   # Equals character
```

The `+` quantifier is probably better (one or more) which is part of ERE (Extended Regular Expressions) so you'd need to used `egrep` (`grep -E`). This means lines that start with an `=` and no variable name will not be matched.

```
$ egrep '^\w+=' file
num=12
length= 128
num= 24 
length= 128
```

**Edit:**

For you secondary question found in the comments, to only print the digit value we get into fancy uses of `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '^\w+=\s?\K\d+' file
12
128
24
128
```

Or use a scripting language like `awk`

```
$ awk -F'= ?' '/\w*=/{print $2}' file
12
128
24 
128
```

Answer (score 3):

Grep allows for regex matching. We can use a regex match with an "or" statement to search for multiple matches.

```
grep 'num=\|length=' file

num=12
length= 128
num= 24 
length= 128
```

the | symbol means "or" in regex. Because this is bash we need to escape the | so it becomes \|

Comment: `bash` has nothing to with why you need to escape `|` it's because `OR` is part of Extended Regular Expressions and by default `grep` only uses Basic Regular Expression. It's it a GNU extension that allows ERE to be used by escaping, alternately drop the escaping and use `egrep/grep-E`.